# In each of the following situations indicate whether...

Tags: asymptotics, computer-science, computational-complexity

**In each of the following situations indicate whether f = O(g), or f = Ω(g), or both (in which case f = Θ(g)).**

**$f(n) = n\log n, \\g(n) = 10n\log10n$**

The solution is saying that both are $O(n\log n) \implies f = \Theta(g)$..

But I don't understand this because I thought that any polynomial dominates any logarithm. So wouldn't the answer be that they are both $O(n) \implies f = \Theta(g)$?

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, I just realized that they are both $O(n\log n)$ because the $n$ is not separate from the $\log n$ which makes them one term. So the solution in the book is in fact correct.